# Vulnerability in the source code, but can't elevate do Privilege Escalation

Tags: linux, vulnerability, c, privilege-escalation

Playing a CTF, I am trying to gain access to level 3 (you have to gain access sequentially from level 1 to level 2 and so on...), and in the level 2 directory there's this source code 2.c and along with it an executable called "2". If you look at the code, you can see the vulnerability that when I run script 2 in the background, I am be able to quickly modify (within the 5s window) the script.sh file in home directory by giving it any command I want it to run. So far I ran the commands in this similar manner echo -e "#!/bin/bash\ncat /var/challenge/level3/devel\n" >> script.sh

With these types of commands I was even able to copy all of its contents and move it to my home directory, and yet no matter what I do, I can't get access to level 3 directory. What am I doing wrong? I tried to do chmod and chown of that file but it still says not permitted.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char buf[1024], path[PATH_MAX + 1];
  int fd, i;

  strcpy(path, getpwuid(getuid()) -> pw_dir); //determine user's home directory
  strcat(path, "/script.sh");
  strcpy(buf, "#!/bin/bash\necho Hello.\ndate\nrm \"$0\"\n");
  umask(0); //set file mode creation

  if ((fd = open(path, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY, 02760)) < 0) { // 276 = --w-rwxrw-
    perror("open");
    return 1;
  }

  write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
  close(fd);
  printf("please wait for us to run your script");
  fflush(stdout);
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf(".");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }

  printf(" starting script\n");
  execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", path, (char * ) 0);
  perror("execl");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear about why this isn't working for you but I can say the comment about the file permissions is incorrect.

Comment: Am I correct that the executable for "2" is setuid?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

It looks like the vulnerability in this code is the use of `strcpy()` and `strcat()` function which are vulnerable to buffer overflow attack. Also, the code is creating a file in user's home directory with hardcoded file name `script.sh` and with full permissions which could be a security risk if the file contain malicious commands.

In the end, I could execute the command and elevate my privileges.

While you run the file `./2 &` in background, use another shell to modify `script.sh` file

Run `l33t` in the modified script

```
echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nl33t" >> script.sh
```